# CMS content disappears with custom layout

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-pages

I'm developing an e-commerce application for a client in Magento 2.1.5. Though this is my first experience with the platform, I have successfully built out a default layout and a handful of application layouts (product view, account pages, etc.). Development was going well until I attempted to make a custom home page layout, which has a different header than the rest of the site.

### The Problem

The CMS content works great when I assign one of the default layouts, such as `1column` or `2columns`, to the home page. When I apply my custom layout, a couple issues occur:

1. All CMS content disappears
2. The footer renders above the header
3. Some containers are missing or disorganized

**With 1column layout (expected result)**

[image]

**With home layout (unexpected result)**
[image]

### Sanity checks

I don't have enough reputation to post more links, so I've listed the titles of stack exchange questions and docs I've used for research.

- Creating a custom homepage template in Magento2
- Magento 2 - Custom Page Layout
- Magento 2: Creating a custom layout
- Official Docs - `/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html`

### Helpful Information

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="custom_home">
    <label translate="true">Home Page Layout</label>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="default"/>
    <!-- changes to layout here -->
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <move element="bmg-wrapper" destination="page.wrapper"/>
    <move element="page.top" destination="bmg-wrapper"/>

    <!-- header -->
    <move element="header.container" destination="bmg-wrapper"/>
    <move element="bmg-header-wrapper" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    <move element="bmg-header" destination="header.container"/>
    <move element="header-wrapper" destination="bmg-header"/>

    <!-- header > top header -->
    <move element="bmg-top-bar" destination="header.container"/>
    <move element="header.panel" destination="bmg-top-nav"/>

    <!-- header > header content -->
    <move element="logo" destination="bmg-logo"/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="bmg-minicart-nav-item" />
    <move element="top.search" destination="bmg-search-nav-item" />
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="store-nav" />
    <move element="wish-list-link" destination="bmg-wish-list-nav-item"/>
    <!--<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true"/>-->

    <!-- content -->
    <move element="bmg-content-container" destination="bmg-wrapper"/>
    <move element="main.content" destination="bmg-content-container"/>
    <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="bmg-content-container" before="-"/>

    <!-- footer -->
    <move element="footer" destination="bmg-footer"/>
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>

    <!-- elements to be removed -->
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>

    <!-- wrapper -->
    <container name="bmg-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-wrapper">
        <!-- top bar -->
        <container name="bmg-top-bar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-top-bar">
            <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                <!-- top bar nav -->
                <container name="bmg-top-nav" htmlTag="nav" htmlClass="bmg-top-nav">
                    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
                        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
                               template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
                    </referenceBlock>
                </container>
                <!-- /top bar nav -->
            </container>
        </container>
        <!-- /top bar -->

        <!-- header -->
        <container name="bmg-header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-header">
            <container name="bmg-header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                <container name="bmg-header-content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                    <container name="bmg-header-nav-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-9">
                        <!-- logo -->
                        <container name="bmg-logo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-logo" before="store-nav">
                            <referenceBlock name="logo">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_dark.png</argument>
                                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">164</argument>
                                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">59</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </referenceBlock>
                        </container>
                        <!-- /logo -->

                        <!-- store nav -->
                        <container name="store-nav" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="store-nav" after="bmg-logo">
                            <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
                                <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">header-nav</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </referenceBlock>
                        </container>
                        <!-- /store nav -->
                    </container>

                    <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-3">
                        <container name="bmg-nav" htmlTag="nav" htmlClass="bmg-nav">
                            <!-- header nav -->
                            <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
                                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </referenceContainer>
                            <!-- /header nav -->

                            <container name="bmg-wish-list-nav-item" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-nav-item">
                                <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link"/>
                            </container>
                            <container name="bmg-minicart-nav-item" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-nav-item">
                                <referenceBlock name="minicart"/>
                            </container>
                            <container name="bmg-search-nav-item" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-nav-item">
                                <referenceBlock name="top.search"/>
                            </container>
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
            <!-- /mobile menu -->
        </container>
        <!-- /header -->

        <container name="bmg-content-container" htmlTag="section" htmlClass="bmg-content container" after="bmg-header">
            <!-- {{ main content }} -->
        </container>

        <!-- footer -->
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bmg-footer">
                <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
                    <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                        <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3">
                            <!-- logo -->
                            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="footer-logo">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_dark.png</argument>
                                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">164</argument>
                                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">59</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                            <!-- /logo -->
                        </container>
                        <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3">
                            <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="footer-nav-stores" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">footer-stores</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                        <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3">
                            <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="footer-nav-account" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">footer-account</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                        <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3">
                            <block class="Ves\Megamenu\Block\Menu" name="footer-nav-bmg" template="Ves_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">footer-bmg</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                    </container>

                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- /footer -->
    </container>
</body>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

- Changed `home_page.xml` to `custom_home.xml`

I discovered similar behavior on the checkout page. Though the checkout page content still renders, the header, footer, and content area are completely out of position.

Comment: rename 'home_page.xml' to 'custom_home.xml', since you have `<layout id="custom_home">`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I changed to the layout to `custom_home.xml`. The layout is still experiencing the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the code for a while, I was able to fix the broken theme.

### Issue 1

I wrapped all content into the `bmg-wrapper` container, including `before.body.end`. Simply removing the following code from the wrapper resolved most of my problems.

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

### Issue 2

Out of ignorance that comes with learning Magento 2, I built the foundation of my layout with custom containers, then moved `referenceBlock` and `referenceContainer` elements into them. Moving common elements around too much caused my theme to break.

I figured out that I can replace the CSS classes of `referenceContainer`'s with my own, which removed the need to create so many custom containers. I was able to rewrite `default.xml` using only 4 `<move>'s` instead of the 17 `<move>'s` seen in my original code. In addition, the rewritten `default.xml` file is 40 lines smaller in length.